# Почему не удается авторизоваться через Roundcube Webmail при указании хоста?

Tags: linux, roundcube

Здравствуйте!
Пытаюсь настроить Roundcube 1.2.2.
Если в файле `/config/config.inc.php` не указывать явно сервер (параметр `default_host`) и порт для подключения по IMAP (параметр `default_port`), 
то авторизация работает, при этом мне достаточно указать только адрес сервера, без порта, и я могу получать/ отправлять письма. Но это не очень удобно, потому что мне нужно вручную прописывать адрес сервера.
А если указать эти параметры, то я получаю ошибку **Неудачное соединение с IMAP сервером**
Roundcube и почтовый сервер работают на Ubuntu Server 16.04
Через почтовый клиент Thunderbird авторизация проходит.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решена. В файле /config/config.inc.php прописал:

```
$config['default_host'] = '%n';
```